# How to disable view renderer from a controller action helper ?

Tags: zend-framework, controller, action, helper, viewhelper

In a controller, I can call viewRenderer helper like this :

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

How can I call viewRenderer in a controller action helper?
Assume that I have a Controller action helper :

```
class Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Ajaxrequest extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract{

   public function test(){
       //what I should do here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`viewRenderer` in your example is actually an *action helper*, not a view helper.

To call action helpers, use the helper broker:

```
$helper = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
$helper->setNoRender(true);
```

If you actually want to call *view helpers*, you need a view instance. You can get one from the controller:

```
$controller = $this->getActionController();

//call the url view helper
$controller->view->url(...);
```

Comment: Hello @jani, I tryed to call the view helper inside an action helper, but had no success with the code you posted, could you try to explain better the usage? Thanks.